# Natural map derivation algorithm

Tags: haskell, covariance, functor, contravariance, denotational-semantics

[This Reddit post by Edward Kmett](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2w05a0/edward_kmett_the_free_theorem_for_fmap/) provides a constructive definition of a **natural map**, the one from the **free theorem** for `fmap` (which I read in yet another [Edward Kmett's post](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap)):

> For given `f`, `g`, `h` and `k`, such that `f . g = h . k`: `$map f . fmap g = fmap h . $map k`, where `$map` is the natural map for the given constructor.

I do not fully understand the algorithm. Let us approach it step-by-step:

> We can define a **"natural map"** by induction over any particular concrete choice of `F` you give.
> Ultimately any such ADT is made out of sums, products, `(->)`'s, `1`s, `0`s, `a`'s, invocations of other
> functors, etc.

Consider:

```
data Smth a = A a a a | B a (Maybe a) | U | Z Void deriving ...
```

No arrows. Let us see how `fmap` (which I reckon to be the **natural** choice for any ADT without `(->)`s in it) would operate here:

```
instance Functor Smth where
  fmap xy (A x x1 x2)  = A (xy x) (xy x1) (xy x2)
  fmap xy (B x xPlus1) = B (xy x) (fmap xy xPlus1) 
  -- One can pattern-match 'xPlus1' as 'Just x1' and 'Nothing'.
  -- From my point of view, 'fmap' suits better here. Reasons below.
  fmap _xy U     = U 
  fmap _xy (Z z) = absurd z
```

Which seems **natural**. To put this more formally, we apply `xy` to every `x`, apply `fmap xy` to every `T x`, where `T` is a `Functor`, we leave every unit unchanged, and we pass every `Void` onto `absurd`. This works for recursive definitions too!

```
data Lst a = Unit | Prepend a (Lst a) deriving ...

instance Functor Lst where
    fmap xy Unit             = Unit
    fmap xy (Prepend x lstX) = Prepend (xy x) (fmap xy lstX)
```

And for the [*non-inductive* types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049683/functors-and-non-inductive-types):<sub>(Detailed explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24049722/11143763) under the linked post.)</sub>

```
Graph a = Node a [Graph a]

instance Functor Graph where
    fmap xy (Node x children) = Node (xy x) (fmap (fmap xy) children)
```

This part is clear.

> When we allow `(->)` we now have the first thing that mixes variance up. The left-hand type argument of `(->)` is in contravariant position, the right-hand side is in covariant position. So you need to track the final type variable through the entire ADT and see if it occurs in positive and/or negative position.

Now we include `(->)`s. Let us try to keep this induction going:

We somehow derived **natural maps** for `T a` and `S a`. Thus, we want to consider the following:

```
data T2S a = T2S (T a -> S a)

instance ?Class? T2S where
    ?map? ?? (T2S tx2sx) = T2S $ \ ty -> ???
```

And I believe this to be the point where we start choosing. We have the following options:

- [**(Phantom)**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:phantom) `a` occurs neither in `T` nor in `S`. `a` in `T2S` is phantom, thus, we can implement both `fmap` and `contramap` as [`const phantom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#v:phantom).
- **(Covariant)** `a` occurs in `S a` and does not occur in `T a`. Thus, this something among the lines of `ReaderT` with `S a` (which does not actually depend on `a`) as environment, which substitutes `?Class?` with `Functor`, `?map?` with `fmap`, `???`, `??` with `xy` with:

  ```
  let tx = phantom ty 
      sx = tx2sx tx
      sy = fmap xy sx
  in sy
  ```
- [**(Contravariant)**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Contravariant) `a` occurs in `T a` and does not occur in `S a`. I do not see a way to make this thing a covariant functor, so we implement a `Contravariant` instance here, which substitutes `?map?` with `contramap`, `??` with `yx`, `???` with:

  ```
  let tx = fmap yx ty 
      sx = tx2sx tx
      sy = phantom sx 
  in sy
  ```
- [**(Invariant)**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.4/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html) `a` occurs both in `T a` and `S a`. We can no longer use `phantom`, which came in quite handy. There is a module [`Data.Functor.Invariant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/invariant-0.4/docs/Data-Functor-Invariant.html) by Edward Kmett. It provides the following class with a map:

  ```
  class Invariant f where
    invmap :: (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> f a -> f b
    -- and some generic stuff...
  ```

  And yet, I cannot see a way to turn this into something we can pluf into the **free theorem** for fmap - the type requires an additional function-argument, which we can't brush off as `id` or something. Anyway, we put `invmap` instead of `?map?`, `xy yx` instead of `??`, and the following instead of `???`:

  ```
  let tx = fmap yx ty 
      sx = tx2sx tx
      sy = fmap xy sx
  in sy
  ```

So, is my understanding of such an algorithm correct? If so, how are we to properly process the **Invariant** case?

Comment: To make `T a -> S a` into a (covariant) functor so to define `fmap`, you essentially need `T` to be a `Contravariant` and `S` to be a (covariant) `Functor`. Then you get something like `fmap (f :: a->b) (myFunction :: T a -> S a) = fmap f . myFunction . contramap f :: T b -> S b`.

Comment: @chi so there are several options within the **Invariant** case? Accordingly, phantom functors are both covariant and contravariant, a feature we use for **Covariant** and **Contravariant** cases. — Thus, we can actually derive `Functor` from the **Invariant** case.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor Well, I think chi is saying that your `invariant` case is incorrectly named. You seem to be consistently assuming that "`a` appears in `t`" actually means "`a` appears covariantly in `t`", which is an incorrect assumption. The type `S a -> T a` could have `a` appearing in both `S a` and `T a` and still be any of covariant, contravariant, or invariant.

Comment: @DanielWagner aha, so, there are 16 cases, instead of 4?

Comment: @DanielWagner Hence Edward Kmett's intuition about the negative/positive positions. If `a` is in negative position in `T a` and phantom in `S a`, it is in negative *times* negative, that is positive, position in `T a -> S a`, and positive *times* negative, that is negative, position in `S a -> T a`. Am I explaining that right? Indeed,  `data T a = T ((a -> Int) -> Int) deriving Functor` works.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor Well, I think there's just 1 case instead of 4, see my answer below. ^_^ But yes, the rest of your explanation sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your algorithm is too complex, because you are trying to write *one* algorithm. Writing two algorithms instead makes things much simpler. One algorithm will build the natural fmap, and the other will build the natural contramap. BUT both algorithms need to be nondeterministic in the following sense: there will be types where they cannot succeed, and so do not return an implementation; and there will be types where there are multiple ways they can succeed, but they're all equivalent.

To start, let's carefully define what it means to be a parameterized type. Here's the different kinds of parameterized types we can have:

```
F ::= F + F'
    | F * F'
    | F -> F'
    | F . F'
    | Id
    | Const X
```

In `Const X`, the `X` ranges over all concrete, non-parameterized types, like `Int` and `Bool` and so forth. And here's their interpretation, i.e. the concrete type they are isomorphic to once given a parameter:

```
[[F + F']] a = Either ([[F]] a) ([[F']] a)
[[F * F']] a = ([[F]] a, [[F']] a)
[[F -> F']] a = [[F]] a -> [[F']] a
[[F . F']] a = [[F]] ([[F']] a)
[[Id]] a = a
[[Const X]] a = X
```

Now we can give our two algorithms. The first bit you've already written yourself:

```
fmap @(F + F') f (Left x) = Left (fmap @F f x)
fmap @(F + F') f (Right x) = Right (fmap @F' f x)
fmap @(F * F') f (x, y) = (fmap @F f x, fmap @F f y)
fmap @(Id) f x = f x
fmap @(Const X) f x = x
```

These correspond to the clauses you gave in your first instance. Then, in your `[Graph a]` example, you gave a clause corresponding to this:

```
fmap @(F . F') f x = fmap @F (fmap @F' f) x
```

That's fine, but this is also the first moment where we get some nondeterminism. One way to make this a functor is indeed nested `fmap`s; but another way is nested `contramap`s.

```
fmap @(F . F') f x = contramap @F (contramap @F' f) x
```

If both clauses are possible, then there are no `Id`s in either `F` or `F'`, so both instances will return `x` unchanged.

The only thing left now is the arrow case, the one you ask about. But it turns out it's very easy in this formalism, there is only one choice:

```
fmap @(F -> F') f x = fmap @F' f . x . contramap @F f
```

That's the whole algorithm, in full detail, for defining the natural `fmap`. ...except one detail, which is the algorithm for the natural `contramap`. But hopefully if you followed all of the above, you can reproduce that algorithm yourself. I encourage you to give it a shot, then check your answers against mine below.

```
contramap @(F + F') f (Left x) = Left (contramap @F f x)
contramap @(F + F') f (Right x) = Right (contramap @F' f x)
contramap @(F * F') f (x, y) = (contramap @F f x, contramap @F' f y)
contramap @(F -> F') f x = contramap @F' f . x . fmap @F f

contramap @(F . F') f x = contramap @F (fmap @F' f) x
-- OR
contramap @(F . F') f x = fmap @F (contramap @F' f) x

-- contramap @(Id) fails
contramap @(Const X) f x = x
```

One thing of interest to me personally: it turns out that `contramap @(Id)` is the only leaf case that fails. All further failures are inductive failures ultimately deriving from this one -- a fact I had never thought of before! (The dual statement is that it turns out that `fmap @(Id)` is the only leaf case that actually uses its first function argument.)

Comment: I surely took my time to respond :P. Will assign a small bounty as interest. Anyway, why do you omit the **third** algorithm for `invmap`? Every `Functor` and `Contravariant` can be made into a `Invariant` (`invmap ab _ba x = fmap ab x`) but not the other way around. Thus, all these cases would fail for, say, `Endo a = a -> a`. I wrote down this algorithm myself. The only trouble is that I got **7** subcases in `F -> F'` case... May I add my algorithm as an edit to your post, so you can decline it, if I am wrong, or accept it, if I am right?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor No deep reason I left it out; just that it's less often used. Or, to fire back: why didn't you ask about the missing algorithm for `Phantom` (which could as well be called `Equivariant`)? ;-) I think teaching this way of thinking -- of defining what building blocks your types are made of and then writing a simple inductive function -- is more important than the details of the actual inductive function built at the end using this technique. Even in the answer already written I debated not explicitly writing out the `contramap` definition.

Comment: well, a phantom type is, as you said under the other post we’ve met under, `Const` in disguise. And we have already derived both `fmap` and `contramap` for `Const`, which can be combined into `phantom`: `() <$ x $< ()`. I guess, that’s what we do when both `fmap` and `contramap` (and `invmap`) are derived.

Comment: [A follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566749/substituting-the-derivation-of-fmap-and-contramap-with-invmap)