# Which kinds of lawfull `Functor`s are possible in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, deriving, fixpoint-combinators

I know following types of `Functor`s:

1. Polynomial functor == simple not-nested parameterized datatype
2. Generalization of 1, by using "parameter removing" newtypes: `Fix`, `Some` (existentials), possibly some GADTs
3. Exponential functor == `X -> a` for fixed X
4. Generalization of 2 to all positive-position functions.
5. Compositions of previous points

It seems like points 2,4,5 can be covered by some conditional instances, like for `Data.Functor.Compose`.

Question:

1. Is my statement correct or I am missing something?
2. Can this be formalized? In particular: what is full list on point 1 and how to fix that points 2,4,5 actually do interfere?
3. Can this be described using `HFunctor`s?

Comment: On (1), the list is missing functors that aren't strictly positive, like `Cont` and `Select`.

Comment: @duplode I was thinking on `Cont` as (main?) example of point 2. Like `a` in `a -> r -> r` is positive position, right?

Comment: In `(a -> r) -> r`, the position of `a` is positive, but not strictly positive. I don't quite see how that would fit as a generalisation of point 1.

Comment: Point 5 is more a theorem *about* functors than a kind of functor: the composition of two functors is always a functor. It might be interesting to try to define the notion of a "prime" functor, one that cannot be defined as the composition of two  other functors.

Comment: Also, two contravariant functors [can be composed to give a covariant one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5.5/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant-Compose.html#t:Compose). This covers *some* of the not strictly positive `Functor`s, such as `Cont`.

Comment: I think you are missing an important generalization of `2`, namely, the generalization to fixpoints of more exotic kinds than `* -> *`.

Comment: You might like [Natural map derivation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67314984/791604).

Comment: @chepner

> Point 5 is more a theorem about functors than a kind of functor

Of course. Still knowing generating set of algebra is useful.

Comment: @duplode

> In (a -> r) -> r, the position of a is positive, but not strictly positive

You right, I set parentheses wrong. For CC you need them left-associative. That seems right to have this as separate case, cuz CC is kinda equivalent to classic logic.